# Securing the transfer of user id from a public computer to the server

Tags: security

The backend of my web app sends requests to GCP text-to-speech on behalf of authorized users. When a user requests speech synthesis, the frontend of my web app sends the user id to the backend. Of course, I assume using HTTPs. Nonetheless, at a public computer, a third person can open the Network tab of the browser tools, and obtain from the request headers the user id that was sent. Thereafter, he can write a client that will pose as an authorized user of my web app. How should such an attack be prevented?

Comment: If a user does not close the browser tab/window and leaves their computer logged into your system, you have a problem. However, for well-designed systems just replaying the network headers will not work. There are many techniques. A simple one-time-use number "salt" is enough to break that problem (replay attacks). My recommendation is to use a well-designed framework such as ASP.NET or Laravel. These types of security issues are solved in their systems. Read their documentation on how they handle these types of problems.

Comment: 1. Why would the problem not be present if they log out? The browser still remembers all the communications for the current tab... 2. I plan to use React.js for frontend and Django for backend. Will I need to solve these types of issues myself?

Comment: If they log out your code should destroy the session so any data left on the client's computer is not useful. There are entire books written on just one part of security - start with cookies and sessions for example. You will need to read those books or study other resources. Once you have a well-defined problem, then create a post. Note: Stack Exchange has a security-related site. https://security.stackexchange.com/